# How to use Turf mask when Polygon has islands in inner rings/inner rings

Tags: polygon, geojson, masking, turf

I am getting some weird result with [turf.mask()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#mask).

This is the `polygon` I am trying to run the `mask()` function with: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Stophface/50155878441205412001247878f58b63/raw/324021868304f96c795e7d8cd18ec2c6f45ee842/polygon.geojson

[image: Raw data]

According to the [docs](https://turfjs.org/docs/#mask), if the mask is undefined, the world extent is used. The result of `turf.mask(polygon, undefined)` is this

[image: Result of mask]

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Stophface/50155878441205412001247878f58b63/raw/5e71fc1c4e4d6815cfa22e15eb1bf10c9208231f/mask_result.geojson

So it is filling the interior ring
Why is it doing that?

The data for the second code snippet of the accepted answere (because I deleted the original question) https://gist.github.com/Stophface/5f0cf7a28466d47f07c83d6d26eba078

Comment: Definition of Turf.js `mask` method states that it "returns a polygon **exterior** ring with holes".  What you want to have is "antihole" in a hole, which `mask` is not capable of. Such a polygon would be multipolygon, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660981/can-a-valid-geojson-polygon-represent-an-island-in-a-lake-in-an-island.

Comment: @TomazicM Hm... Is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be simpler way of solving this problem by using some library, but one possible way with only Turf.js would be to:

- create array of outer liner rings and array of inner linear rings of polygon (with later reverse coordinate order);
- create multi polygon from outer linear rings and mask it;
- get linear rings of created masked polygon and append saved inner liner rings;
- create multi polygon from this array of rings.

Code could then look something like this:

```js
var coords = turf.getCoords(polygon);

var outerRings = [];
var innerRings = [];

coords.forEach(function(polyCoords) {
  polyCoords.forEach(function(linearRing, i) {
    if (i == 0)
      outerRings.push(linearRing);
    else {
      var poly = turf.rewind(turf.polygon([linearRing]));
      innerRings.push(turf.getCoords(poly)[0]);
    }
  })
});
var outerRingsPoly = turf.multiPolygon([outerRings]);

var maskedOuterRingsPoly = turf.mask(outerRingsPoly);
var maskedOuterRings = turf.getCoords(maskedOuterRingsPoly);
var allRings = maskedOuterRings.concat(innerRings);

var finalPoly = turf.multiPolygon([allRings]);
```

Result then looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT**: When testing again with GeoJSON with several holes, turf.js complained executing `var coords = turf.getCoords(polygon)`, so I had to change logic a bit.

Here is modified code:

```js
var outerRings = [];
var innerRings = [];

turf.geomEach(polygon, function(geom) {
  geom.coordinates[0].forEach(function(linearRing, i) {
    if (i == 0)
      outerRings.push(linearRing);
    else {
      var poly = turf.rewind(turf.polygon([linearRing]));
      innerRings.push(turf.getCoords(poly)[0]);
    }
  });
});

var outerRingsPoly = turf.multiPolygon([outerRings]);

var maskedOuterRingsPoly = turf.mask(outerRingsPoly);
var maskedOuterRings = turf.getCoords(maskedOuterRingsPoly);
var allRings = maskedOuterRings.concat(innerRings);

var finalPoly = turf.multiPolygon([allRings]);
```

And here the result:

[image]

Comment: That works really very well. I build a more complex function handling more cases upon your answer and posted it here too, for others to reuse. However, there is one case which I cannot seem to handle. When there is a hole in an Polygon, that exceeds the polygons boundaries. In my posted answer this is the case with the square geometry. Do you have a hot hint, how to handle this situation?

Comment: GIS SE site has policy of focused questions, which means one question per question. If you have a new/additional question, please post it as a separate question.

Comment: I deleted my previous follow up question and here is a new one https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/452807/extracting-inner-rings-of-polygon-creates-falsy-geojson

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Displaying it somewhere else than geojson.io works!

Comment: Hey, there is a follow up question you might be interested in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462343/mask-geojson-with-nested-polygons-nested-donuts

Comment: @four-eyes OK, I'll check.