# Mask GeoJSON with nested Polygons/Nested donuts

Tags: polygon, geojson, masking, turf, donut-polygons

How would I mask a `geojson`  that looks like this

[image: screenshot of map]

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[102,2],[103,2],[103,3],[102,3],[102,2]]],[[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]],[[100.2,0.2],[100.2,0.8],[100.8,0.8],[100.8,0.2],[100.2,0.2]]],[[[100.3,0.3],[100.7,0.3],[100.7,0.7],[100.3,0.7],[100.3,0.3]],[[100.4305160192801,0.67817296142852],[100.43926588878527,0.6777431305923907],[100.44793148784716,0.6764577778174132],[100.45642935778174,0.6743292824257617],[100.46467765559704,0.6713781440787653],[100.47259694234847,0.667632785305691],[100.48011094831709,0.6631292777150927],[100.48714730763562,0.6579109945286341],[100.49363825528266,0.6520281927874464],[100.49952127973005,0.6455375292587178],[100.50473972495757,0.6385015147088778],[100.50924333603814,0.6309879118031904],[100.5129887430422,0.6230690824341719],[100.51593987860606,0.6148212907677792],[100.51806832514795,0.6063239687221135],[100.51935358839506,0.5976589509544159],[100.51978329459449,0.5889096867249723],[100.51935330951578,0.5801604362283926],[100.51806777810651,0.5714954591315431],[100.51593908442491,0.56299820313176],[100.51298773224117,0.5547505003481902],[100.50924214746165,0.5468317792832317],[100.50473840428187,0.5393182999407914],[100.49951987770788,0.5322824194649319],[100.4936368257929,0.5257918953685365],[100.48714590561279,0.5199092330597317],[100.48010962764015,0.5146910839473947],[100.47259575377038,0.5101876999202546],[100.46467664479428,0.5064424494514895],[100.45642856359898,0.503491399987565],[100.4479309408045,0.5013629706420072],[100.43926560990533,0.5000776585380188],[100.4305160192801,0.49964784143480295],[100.42176642865488,0.5000776585380188],[100.41310109775573,0.5013629706420072],[100.40460347496123,0.503491399987565],[100.39635539376593,0.5064424494514895],[100.38843628478985,0.5101876999202546],[100.38092241092006,0.5146910839473947],[100.37388613294743,0.5199092330597317],[100.3673952127673,0.5257918953685367],[100.36151216085236,0.5322824194649319],[100.35629363427834,0.5393182999407915],[100.35178989109856,0.5468317792832317],[100.34804430631903,0.5547505003481902],[100.34509295413531,0.56299820313176],[100.34296426045371,0.5714954591315431],[100.34167872904445,0.5801604362283926],[100.34124874396572,0.5889096867249723],[100.34167845016515,0.5976589509544159],[100.34296371341229,0.6063239687221135],[100.34509215995416,0.6148212907677792],[100.34804329551801,0.6230690824341718],[100.35178870252209,0.6309879118031904],[100.35629231360264,0.6385015147088778],[100.36151075883018,0.6455375292587178],[100.36739378327755,0.6520281927874465],[100.37388473092459,0.6579109945286342],[100.3809210902431,0.6631292777150927],[100.38843509621175,0.667632785305691],[100.39635438296318,0.6713781440787653],[100.40460268077847,0.6743292824257617],[100.41310055071305,0.6764577778174132],[100.42176614977494,0.6777431305923907],[100.4305160192801,0.67817296142852]]],[[[101.2,0.2],[101.8,0.2],[101.8,0.8],[101.2,0.8],[101.2,0.2]],[[101.3,0.3],[101.3,0.7],[101.7,0.7],[101.7,0.3],[101.3,0.3]]]]},"properties":{"name":"Dinagat Islands"}}]}
```

As you can see, the bottom left polygon is in the shape of a 'nested donut'.
This is what I have so far (which I have adapted from [this answere)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451527/how-to-use-turf-mask-when-polygon-has-islands-in-inner-rings-inner-rings)

```
const maskWithPossibleInnerRings = (geometry, cover) => {
  const coords = turf.getCoords(geometry);
  const outerRings = [];
  const innerRings = [];
  coords.forEach(function (polyCoords) {
    polyCoords.forEach(function (linearRing, i) {
      if (i == 0) {
        outerRings.push([linearRing]);
      } else {
        var poly = turf.rewind(turf.polygon([linearRing]));
        innerRings.push(turf.getCoords(poly)[0]);
      }
    });
  });
  const outerRingsPoly = turf.multiPolygon(outerRings);
  const maskedOuterRingsPoly = turf.mask(outerRingsPoly, cover);
  const maskedOuterRings = turf.getCoords(maskedOuterRingsPoly);
  const allRings = [maskedOuterRings];
  innerRings.forEach(innerRing => allRings.push([innerRing]));
  const finalPoly = turf.multiPolygon(allRings);
  console.log('RESULT')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(finalPoly))
  return finalPoly;
};
```

The result looks like this

[image: result map screenshot]

Not quite what I want. I think the problem starts here:

```
  const outerRingsPoly = turf.multiPolygon(outerRings);
```

`outerRingsPoly` looks like this

[image: polygon creation]

which is a problem for the next line

```
const maskedOuterRingsPoly = turf.mask(outerRingsPoly, cover);
```

`maskedOuterRingsPoly` looks like this

[image: polygon mask result]

So only the largest polygon gets used for `mask()`. I want the result to look like this though

[image: result screen shot]

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[180,90],[-180,90],[-180,-90],[180,-90],[180,90]],[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]],[[101.2,0.2],[101.8,0.2],[101.8,0.8],[101.2,0.8],[101.2,0.2]],[[102,2],[103,2],[103,3],[102,3],[102,2]]],[[[100.2,0.2],[100.2,0.8],[100.8,0.8],[100.8,0.2],[100.2,0.2]],[[100.3,0.3],[100.7,0.3],[100.7,0.7],[100.3,0.7],[100.3,0.3]]],[[[100.4305160192801,0.67817296142852],[100.43926588878527,0.6777431305923907],[100.44793148784716,0.6764577778174132],[100.45642935778174,0.6743292824257617],[100.46467765559704,0.6713781440787653],[100.47259694234847,0.667632785305691],[100.48011094831709,0.6631292777150927],[100.48714730763562,0.6579109945286341],[100.49363825528266,0.6520281927874464],[100.49952127973005,0.6455375292587178],[100.50473972495757,0.6385015147088778],[100.50924333603814,0.6309879118031904],[100.5129887430422,0.6230690824341719],[100.51593987860606,0.6148212907677792],[100.51806832514795,0.6063239687221135],[100.51935358839506,0.5976589509544159],[100.51978329459449,0.5889096867249723],[100.51935330951578,0.5801604362283926],[100.51806777810651,0.5714954591315431],[100.51593908442491,0.56299820313176],[100.51298773224117,0.5547505003481902],[100.50924214746165,0.5468317792832317],[100.50473840428187,0.5393182999407914],[100.49951987770788,0.5322824194649319],[100.4936368257929,0.5257918953685365],[100.48714590561279,0.5199092330597317],[100.48010962764015,0.5146910839473947],[100.47259575377038,0.5101876999202546],[100.46467664479428,0.5064424494514895],[100.45642856359898,0.503491399987565],[100.4479309408045,0.5013629706420072],[100.43926560990533,0.5000776585380188],[100.4305160192801,0.49964784143480295],[100.42176642865488,0.5000776585380188],[100.41310109775573,0.5013629706420072],[100.40460347496123,0.503491399987565],[100.39635539376593,0.5064424494514895],[100.38843628478985,0.5101876999202546],[100.38092241092006,0.5146910839473947],[100.37388613294743,0.5199092330597317],[100.3673952127673,0.5257918953685367],[100.36151216085236,0.5322824194649319],[100.35629363427834,0.5393182999407915],[100.35178989109856,0.5468317792832317],[100.34804430631903,0.5547505003481902],[100.34509295413531,0.56299820313176],[100.34296426045371,0.5714954591315431],[100.34167872904445,0.5801604362283926],[100.34124874396572,0.5889096867249723],[100.34167845016515,0.5976589509544159],[100.34296371341229,0.6063239687221135],[100.34509215995416,0.6148212907677792],[100.34804329551801,0.6230690824341718],[100.35178870252209,0.6309879118031904],[100.35629231360264,0.6385015147088778],[100.36151075883018,0.6455375292587178],[100.36739378327755,0.6520281927874465],[100.37388473092459,0.6579109945286342],[100.3809210902431,0.6631292777150927],[100.38843509621175,0.667632785305691],[100.39635438296318,0.6713781440787653],[100.40460268077847,0.6743292824257617],[100.41310055071305,0.6764577778174132],[100.42176614977494,0.6777431305923907],[100.4305160192801,0.67817296142852]]],[[[101.3,0.3],[101.3,0.7],[101.7,0.7],[101.7,0.3],[101.3,0.3]]]]}}]}
```

How would I go on about masking polygons with a varying deep number of outer- and innerrings when I must do it in GeoJson? What kind of "rule" should I follow?

1. Find outer most rings (how)?
2. Apply proposed code (see above) to all most outer rings
3. Do some winding to all the other outer- and inner rings
4. Put everything together

Here is a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/86x0bj5t/2/

Comment: Please do not delete and repost Questions. Not only does it mess with the history, but doing so can spur the automated SE anti-spam defenses to block your account.

Comment: If I check you complex GeoJSON on https://geojsonlint.com/ site, I get this error: **Invalid GeoJSON: Line 1: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule**

Comment: @TomazicM The "original" unmasked, or the result?

Comment: Original. I suspect donut circle has wrong orientation. You can check orientation with the `turf.booleanClockwise` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem when masking complex multipolygon is with polygons which are inside hole of another polygon. These polygons have to be treated a bit differently:

- Outer ring of such polygon has to become inner ring (hole) of the enclosing polygon.
- Inner ring (hole) of such a polygon should be added to multipolygon collection as a regular polygon.

Proof of concept code for the multipolygon from the question could then look something like this:

```js
const outerRings = [];
const innerRings = [];
const outerToInnerLink = [];
const enclosedOuterRings = [];

coords.forEach(function (polyCoords, j) {
  polyCoords.forEach(function (linearRing, i) {
    if (i == 0) {
      outerRings.push([linearRing]);
    } else {
      let poly = turf.polygon([linearRing]);
      if (turf.booleanClockwise(linearRing)) {
        poly = turf.rewind(poly);
      }
      outerToInnerLink[j] = innerRings.length;
      innerRings.push(turf.getCoords(poly));
    }
  });
});

innerRings.forEach(function(innerRing, i) {
  outerRings.forEach(function(outerRing, j) {
    if (turf.booleanContains(turf.polygon(innerRing), turf.polygon(outerRing))) {
      enclosedOuterRings.push([i, j]);
    }
  });
});

function rewindLinearRing(linearRing) {
  let poly = turf.polygon([linearRing]);
  poly = turf.rewind(poly);
  return(turf.getCoords(poly)[0]);
}

const addedRings = [];
enclosedOuterRings.slice().reverse().forEach(function(enclosedOuterRing) {
  const outerRingInd = enclosedOuterRing[1];
  const enclosedRing = outerRings[outerRingInd];
  const enclosingRing = innerRings[enclosedOuterRing[0]];
  enclosingRing.push(rewindLinearRing(enclosedRing[0]));
  outerRings.splice(outerRingInd, 1);
  if (outerToInnerLink[outerRingInd]) {
    addedRings.push([rewindLinearRing(innerRings[outerToInnerLink[outerRingInd]][0])]);
    innerRings.splice(outerToInnerLink[outerRingInd], 1);
  }
});

const outerRingsPoly = turf.multiPolygon(outerRings);
const maskedOuterRingsPoly = turf.mask(outerRingsPoly, null);
const maskedOuterRings = turf.getCoords(maskedOuterRingsPoly);
const allRings = [maskedOuterRings];
allRings.push(...innerRings);
allRings.push(...addedRings);
const finalPoly = turf.multiPolygon(allRings);
```

This is the result (using Leaflet for display):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will check after the weekend. I surely have some questions!

Comment: Hey TomazicM, thanks for taking the time to look into this. And sorry that it took me so long for responding... This looks really very neat. The problem I am facing is, that the level of nesting of the polygons can be of varying depth... Looking at the lower left polygon, there could be two or ten more polygons that are nested inside this, creating holes. Is there a way to handle this situation?

Comment: Usually such problems are dealt with recursion. How this would look in this case, it's up to you to find out, I won't go into it.

Comment: Alright, thank you. When I come to a conlcusion, I will share the results with you. Might be useful to have this in a toolbox saved somewhere :)

Comment: I am studying your code and I must admit, I am quite challenged :) I do not think that recursion is needed here, because the GeoJSON data structure is not infinitely nested. And I think the only case your proof of concept is not covering is this one http://jsonblob.com/1132302176595755008 I am trying to adjust your code to account for this. However, I am having trouble understanding this line `outerToInnerLink[j] = innerRings.length;`. The result of this is `[undefined, 0, 1, 2]`. Why is the link the `length` of the `innerRings`?

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. The code TomazicM provided is awesome. There is a library ([JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts)) doing this for you though. It works with `geometries`  and not with Geojson though.

```
const complexGeometry = JSON.parse('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[102,2],[103,2],[103,3],[102,3],[102,2]]],[[[100,0],[101,0],[101,1],[100,1],[100,0]],[[100.2,0.2],[100.2,0.8],[100.8,0.8],[100.8,0.2],[100.2,0.2]]],[[[100.3,0.3],[100.7,0.3],[100.7,0.7],[100.3,0.7],[100.3,0.3]],[[100.4305160192801,0.67817296142852],[100.42176614977494,0.6777431305923907],[100.41310055071305,0.6764577778174132],[100.40460268077847,0.6743292824257617],[100.39635438296318,0.6713781440787653],[100.38843509621175,0.667632785305691],[100.3809210902431,0.6631292777150927],[100.37388473092459,0.6579109945286342],[100.36739378327755,0.6520281927874465],[100.36151075883018,0.6455375292587178],[100.35629231360264,0.6385015147088778],[100.35178870252209,0.6309879118031904],[100.34804329551801,0.6230690824341718],[100.34509215995416,0.6148212907677792],[100.34296371341229,0.6063239687221135],[100.34167845016515,0.5976589509544159],[100.34124874396572,0.5889096867249723],[100.34167872904445,0.5801604362283926],[100.34296426045371,0.5714954591315431],[100.34509295413531,0.56299820313176],[100.34804430631903,0.5547505003481902],[100.35178989109856,0.5468317792832317],[100.35629363427834,0.5393182999407915],[100.36151216085236,0.5322824194649319],[100.3673952127673,0.5257918953685367],[100.37388613294743,0.5199092330597317],[100.38092241092006,0.5146910839473947],[100.38843628478985,0.5101876999202546],[100.39635539376593,0.5064424494514895],[100.40460347496123,0.503491399987565],[100.41310109775573,0.5013629706420072],[100.42176642865488,0.5000776585380188],[100.4305160192801,0.49964784143480295],[100.43926560990533,0.5000776585380188],[100.4479309408045,0.5013629706420072],[100.45642856359898,0.503491399987565],[100.46467664479428,0.5064424494514895],[100.47259575377038,0.5101876999202546],[100.48010962764015,0.5146910839473947],[100.48714590561279,0.5199092330597317],[100.4936368257929,0.5257918953685365],[100.49951987770788,0.5322824194649319],[100.50473840428187,0.5393182999407914],[100.50924214746165,0.5468317792832317],[100.51298773224117,0.5547505003481902],[100.51593908442491,0.56299820313176],[100.51806777810651,0.5714954591315431],[100.51935330951578,0.5801604362283926],[100.51978329459449,0.5889096867249723],[100.51935358839506,0.5976589509544159],[100.51806832514795,0.6063239687221135],[100.51593987860606,0.6148212907677792],[100.5129887430422,0.6230690824341719],[100.50924333603814,0.6309879118031904],[100.50473972495757,0.6385015147088778],[100.49952127973005,0.6455375292587178],[100.49363825528266,0.6520281927874464],[100.48714730763562,0.6579109945286341],[100.48011094831709,0.6631292777150927],[100.47259694234847,0.667632785305691],[100.46467765559704,0.6713781440787653],[100.45642935778174,0.6743292824257617],[100.44793148784716,0.6764577778174132],[100.43926588878527,0.6777431305923907],[100.4305160192801,0.67817296142852]]],[[[101.2,0.2],[101.8,0.2],[101.8,0.8],[101.2,0.8],[101.2,0.2]],[[101.3,0.3],[101.3,0.7],[101.7,0.7],[101.7,0.3],[101.3,0.3]]]]}')

const coverGeometry = JSON.parse('{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-180,-90],[180,-90],[180,90],[-180,90],[-180,-90]]]}')

const reader = new jsts.io.GeoJSONReader();
const writer = new jsts.io.GeoJSONWriter();
const coverJsts = reader.read(coverGeometry)
const complexGeometryJsts = reader.read(complexGeometry)
const difference = jsts.operation.overlay.OverlayOp.difference(coverJsts, complexGeometryJsts)
const result = writer.write(difference)
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

If you want to get the `geometry` of a GeoJSON, you can use turf's [getGeom](https://turfjs.org/docs/#getGeom)()